# What would you suggest: As the efficient method for Language Translation?

Tags: php, language-translation

Making a website cross-language friendly is being considered as the NEXT TREND. On this situation.. what method would be considered as good, efficient in terms development complexity.

### The available options I Know are

- Uploading the content is each languages I need separately (which is a little unfriendly, if I have wide range of languages)
- Using `Google Translation` (But I don't like this, as it shows google header at the top)

Are there any other ways to translate content to another language? and Which one of them is efficient based on the factors like: performance, coding time and flexibility.

Comment: Nothing beats throwing cold, hard cash at a human translator.

Comment: @The Close Voter, What is `ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered` in this question? X(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start i would have to agree with Ignacio , nothing beats a human translator , if you don't have the time then once somebody enters new text it could get parsed in different languages with GTranslate api , and then saved to database and feeded to the user based on his prefered language , using gtranslate api whont show any google translate logo check this out :

```
<?php
require("GTranslate.php");

 try{
       $gt = new Gtranslate;
       echo "Translating [Hello World] from English to German => ".$gt->english_to_german("hello world")."<br/>";
        echo "Translating [Ciao mondo] Italian to English => ".$gt->it_to_en("Ciao mondo")."<br/>";
 } catch (GTranslateException $ge)
 {
       echo $ge->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

Instead of echo you could save the translated text inside a database just like you would do it if there where a number of human translators .

You can download GTranslate api from [GTranslate on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gtranslate-api-php/)